# How to binary data from a get response using jersey client?

Tags: java, rest, jersey-client

I am trying to make a rest Get call using jersey client. Base on the api docs, the request returns an image as binary data. When I make the rest Get call using postman, I can the actual image back (im asumming postman converts the binary back to image/png). This is the following headers that is returned from postman.

[image]

I try making the rest Get using jersey client in java. Here is my code:

```
private Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient( new ClientConfig().register(LoggingFilter.class).register(MultiPartFeature.class));
private WebTarget myServer;

myServer= client.target(baseURL);

 public void restGetImage(String requestURL, String headers) {

    BufferedReader br = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line;

    MultivaluedMap<String, Object> userHeaders = storeHeadersInMap(headers);

    WebTarget target = getWebTarget().path(requestURL);

    Response response = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                     .headers(userHeaders)
                     .get();

    System.out.println("Reuqest URL: " + session.get("baseurl") + requestURL);
    int responseCode = response.getStatus();
    InputStream inputStream = response.readEntity(InputStream.class);

    String contentType = response.getHeaderString("Content-Type");

 //     br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
//      
//      try {
  //            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
  //                sb.append(line);
 //         }
  //            
 //         br.close(); //close buffered reader 
  //        
 //     } catch (IOException e) {
 //         e.printStackTrace();
//          
//      }
//      
//      RestResponse data = new RestResponse(responseCode, sb.toString(), contentType);
//      data.setResponseHeader(response.getHeaders());
//      
//      System.out.println("response code: " + responseCode);
//      System.out.println("response Content-Type: " + contentType);
//      System.out.println("Response body: " + sb.toString());

//      return data;
    }
```

Please excuse all the comments because I am still testing the code. Basically the code returns 200 response status, but when it fails to read the response. It throws an exception at InputStream inputStream = response.readEntity(InputStrean.class).

```
 Apr 22, 2016 11:37:29 AM         
 org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderIn
terceptor aroundReadFrom
SEVERE: MessageBodyReader not found for media type=image/png, type=class   
com.itextpdf.text.pdf.codec.Base64$InputStream, genericType=class   
com.itextpdf.text.pdf.codec.Base64$InputStream.
```

My goal is to be able to read the binary response data. Any insight is apprectiated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> SEVERE: MessageBodyReader not found for media type=image/png, type=class
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.codec.Base64$InputStream, genericType=class
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.codec.Base64$InputStream.

You're using the wrong `InputStream` class. You should be using [`java.io.InputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/omg/CORBA/portable/InputStream.html). Check and fix your import.

Comment: omg your right! Thank you so much. Such a silly mistake by me. I was so confused.